# Qt OpenGL compile Static

Tags: qt, opengl, static-libraries

I wrote a small app with qt and opengl ([code](https://github.com/vdamatto/A-star-search-algorithm)) and I want to compile it static now.

So i downloaded Qt library and compile it static using this [guide](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/deployment-windows.html).

I added a line CONFIG += static to the pro file cd to the project location and hit:

```
make clean
qmake -config release
make
```

but I am getting several undefined references like:

```
qpixmapdata_gl.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to `_imp___Z14qt_defaultDpiYv'
```

What I am doing wrong? Do I need to add the libs to the pro file? How do I do this and more important what libs should I use?

I tried something like this with no result:

```
LIBS += C:\Qt\4.7.3\bin\QtOpenGL4.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that symbol is defined in qfont.cpp, so it should be there. I would try to add:

```
QT += gui
```

in your .pro file. And I suppose you need:

```
QT += core
```

also.

EDIT: Try also to check that the symbol is included in the libQtGui.lib and the line used to compile.
Are you using the same compiler also? The mangling reported seems that of gcc. Did you compile Qt libraries with mingw or nmake?

Comment: core and gui modules are included by default, you don't need to specify it - see [link](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-qt-libraries)

Comment: I suppose they intend it is the default when using default specification files bundled with Qt. If custom specification files are used or maybe something different than the defaults those values can be decided by the designer and must be included if not already included.

Comment: I compiled both libraries and app with mingw.

Comment: Adding gui and core didn't changed anything. What do you mean by _Try also to check that the symbol is included in the libQtGui.lib and the line used to compile?_

Comment: Try to use an utility that shows you the symbols which are defined inside the library (mingw should have its own nm command to do this), so that you can check where is the symbol qt_defaultDpiY and what is the mangling. If you're using mingw than what are the parameters passed to mingw when compiling? So that we can see how it is linking and to what.